# Can 集合 be used to refer to a meeting between 2 people only?

Tags: word-usage

Not a lot of context is necessary I think, just this line a person said to their friend: じゃあ、今からいつもの場所に集合ね

I'm not sure if this 集合 implies a group gathering between friends (more than 2) or if it can also just refers to the 2 of them. I usually see 場所集合 used when talking about groups of people so I'm not sure.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say I won't find it odd if 集合 is used when (only) two people gather. Actually, as I searched my inbox, I found myself saying 「集合はどこにしましょう」，「現地集合でいいですか」 etc. to some friends of mine when I was going to meet one friend,  not more.
集合, rather than 会う meet, is useful when we meet somewhere and then go elsewhere together.

I might not be the majority, but I'd like to imagine that the majority of the native speakers will feel confortable with using  "現地集合" at least, when only two people are meeting.

As @DXV says, 待ち合わせ is another word that can convey the similar meaning.

Comment: This is a very very crude research but googling for デート/彼女/彼氏 + "集合" (note the quote) reveals certain amount of usage regarding 集合時間 and 現地集合 in the context of dating.

Comment: Right, I’ve also heard 集合 used for only two people. Yet, I’ve *also* heard people on the receiving end interpret it as more people coming and leading to confusion. So I tend to use 待ち合わせ to be safe, but I think many people consider it as fine for two people...

Comment: +1, I also use 集合 without hesitation when I meet only one person. I'd say it's not odd at all. Still, statistically speaking, 集合 may be relatively less common when there are only two people, as compared to when there are three or more.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure if this 集合 implies a group gathering between friends (more than 2) or if it can also just refers to the 2 of them. I usually see 場所集合 used when talking about groups of people so I'm not sure.

I would think it would be really odd to native Japanese speakers if only your friend had said "集合" to try  to mean virtually "mutual meeting".

[**Weblio**](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%9B%86%E5%90%88) says,

> しゅう ごう しふがふ ［0］ 【集合】
>   （ 名 ） スル
>   ① いくつかのものを一か所に集めること。また、集まること。聚合。 
>   Translated
>
> しゅうごう　集合
>   Gather particularly unspecific people or things to the one place. Or they meet or be collected as a mass at the place.

Native Japanese speakers expect 3 or 4 more people would gather at one place when we hear the word 集合。　Not suitable for 2 people's meeting.

Comment: +1. Just like to add that 待ち合わせ場所 / 待ち合わせ時間 are also commonly used to refer to meeting place and meeting time, respectively. It can apply to just 2 people.